# how to quickly play numbers of videos on collectionView like Tiktok?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview

I'm building a video list view(using collectionView) like the Tiktok app. I'm adding AVPlayerLayer on imageView(for each cellItem) and playing AVPlayer on that, taking a few time to load the video layer. Can anyone suggest how we can fetch video data for the player before going on the video page to make the video page more smooth???

Please check the below code what I'm doing wrong in that??

```
func setupVideoFor(url: String, completion: @escaping COMPLETION_HANDLER = {_ in}) {
        if self.videoCache.object(forKey: url as NSString) != nil {
            return
        }
        
        guard let URL = URL(string: url) else {
            return
        }
        
        didVideoStartPlay = completion
        
        let asset = AVURLAsset(url: URL)
        let requestedKeys = ["playable"]
        asset.loadValuesAsynchronously(forKeys: requestedKeys) { [weak self] in
            guard let strongSelf = self else {
                return
            }
            /**
             Need to check whether asset loaded successfully, if not successful then don't create
             AVPlayer and AVPlayerItem and return without caching the videocontainer,
             so that, the assets can be tried to be downloaded again when need be.
             */
            var error: NSError? = nil
            let status = asset.statusOfValue(forKey: "playable", error: &error)
            switch status {
                case .loaded:
                    break
                case .failed, .cancelled:
                    print("Failed to load asset successfully")
                    return
                default:
                    print("Unkown state of asset")
                    return
            }
            let player = AVPlayer()
            let item = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                let videoContainer = VideoContainer(player: player, item: item, url: url)
                strongSelf.videoCache.setObject(videoContainer, forKey: url as NSString)
                videoContainer.player.replaceCurrentItem(with: videoContainer.playerItem)
                
                /**
                 Try to play video again in case when playvideo method was called and
                 asset was not obtained, so, earlier video must have not run
                 */
                if strongSelf.videoURL == url, let layer = strongSelf.currentLayer {
                    strongSelf.duration = asset.duration
                    strongSelf.playVideo(withLayer: layer, url: url)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on a few factors...

AVPlayer is a way to control what happens to an `AVPlayerItem`, and `AVPlayerLayer` is just the display layer for that.

You want to look into `AVPlayerItem`. You can initialize a number of `AVPlayerItem` objects without passing them to the `AVPlayer`.  You can observe each of their `status` properties (with KVO) to know when they are ready to play. You could do this before showing any video layer at all, then pass the *ready* AVPlayerItem objects to the AVPlayer, and that could give the perception of speeded up video.

Also, you might consider looking at your video's HLS manifest. You can check errors of the manifest itself with `mediastreamvalidator` which can be found (along with other tools) over here. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/http_live_streaming/about_apple_s_http_live_streaming_tools

This tool will inspect how the playlist is set up, and report any number of errors, including ones that would affect performance. For example, if the initial bitrate (what the player will try to play before it figures out data about network conditions, etc) is set too high, this could lead to long loading times.